# append data to existing file

Tags: java, android

I have created a file in internal storage from which i want to read and write data. I want to append the new data in the existing file but my codes replaces all the data that is already written in the file with the new data. Here the code of function that writes data.

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("Privatelist.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Writing to file"+data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();              

        outputStreamWriter.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reach your target in two ways:

**WAY 1**:

Add a BufferedWritter to append the data:

```
BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
fbw.write("append txt...");
```

After, you must close the `BufferedWritter`, it will also close your `OutputStreamWriter`.

```
fbw.close();
```

Your code will be like this:

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("Privatelist.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
        fbw.write(data);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Writing to file"+data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();              

        fbw.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());

    } 
}
```

**WAY 2**

There is more generic class `FileOutputStream` which has a constructor `FileOutputStream( File file, boolean append )`. If you set parameter `append=true` your existing file will not be overwritten:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Privatelist.txt", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should .Append(data), not .write(data),

though i'd use [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)
It's an inherited class of OutputStreamWriter and it allows you to define in the constructer weither you want to append to the start or end of the file with each write